# Using java in JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, tomcat

So I wanted to create new Country object in jsp file. When I do:

```
Country test = new Country("Poland");
```

In normal file.java it works all ok. But when I try to do this in jsp file I have errors:

```
An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Country cannot be resolved to a type
14: <br>
15: <h3>Date=<%= new Date() %>
16:
17: <% Country test = new Country("Poland"); %>
18: </h3>
19: </body>
20: </html>

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my all jsp file:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="pl.marek.reader.*" %>
<%@page import="pl.marek.preparer.*" %>
<%@page import="pl.marek.country.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h3>Date=<%= new Date() %>

<% Country test = new Country("Poland"); %>

</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong? By the way, I'm totally new in doing java dynamic pages, I just started read some tutorials today.

BTW2. I'm using maven. It's maven project, where I chosen "maven-archetype-webapp".

Comment: Did you deploy your classes or jars to the right location inside Tomcat?

Comment: I just clicked right in Eclipse -> Servers -> Tomcat and chosen "Add and remove" and here I selected myFirstWebProject. I have to do something more?

Comment: Well how does your code get deployed to Tomcat? Your classes need to go to webapps/<your-webapp>/WEB-INF/classes and your jars to webapps/<your-webapp>/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: But here is little problem. In myFirstWebProject -> pom.xml I'm doing "dependencies", because I'm using classes from other modules. 
In myFirstWebProject -> DeployedResources I have ">webapp" and I can't open it. Also I have "web-resources" -> "META-INF" -> "maven" and "MANIFEST.MF" -> "pl.marek" -> "myFirstWebProject" -> "pom.properties" and "pom.xml"

Comment: *What I'm doing wrong?* - Using scriplets.

Comment: Could you show us the country class?

Comment: Now I deployed file ".war" like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9X9DA8oVodk And now I see "Hello world!" instead of "Hello. Date=Mon Aug 31 .......".

Comment: I have no idea why, but now it started to work oO